# What happened to Hampnie Hambart in Episode 3?

Tags: sunday-without-god

When Hampnie Hambart died, was it because his wish came true AND he succumbed to his wounds, or would he have died whether he was wounded or not because his wish came true? I'm asking because I don't recall him being that terribly wounded. It seemed like the group that captured him was just getting started.

Comment: You have no need to add a spoiler warning in the title. If you feel that something might be spoilerish add `>!` before the sentence or paragraph, to hide the spoiler content until a user mouses over it. With that being said, your title implies a spoilers so you don't really need to include one if you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you for @Krazer! In the past I've written a spoilery title and didn't want it to happen again, but also I wanted to make sure I wrote a proper title for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure, but it makes sense why he would die if we accept Hampnie Hambart's own theory for what God is doing. He believes that God thinks he is granting humans their wishes. In that case, Hampnie Hambart's own wish, to die happy with his family, was granted. Until that point, he was unable to die because it would go against his wish. However, once those conditions were met, he could die just as any other human.

As for his wounds not being very severe, this is a matter of how you interpret the scene. My personal guess he was probably at the level that an ordinary human would die, but being immortal himself, he could withstand more than the average human. Another possibility is that after his conditions were met, his wish being his own death, God granted him that wish right away. What exactly the group does to him isn't depicted much so we can't know for sure whether it would kill a normal person. There may be more information in the light novels, but I haven't read them.

Of course, we don't really know what God is doing (at least not yet), so there could be a different explanation, but this makes sense given all that we know so far by episode 3 of the anime.

Comment: Very true! I believe that he died when his wish was granted. His wish was to die with his family, which is why he was searching for Hana. He would not be able to die unless he knew what happened to her. Once he found out she passed away, and that he still has family who will remember him and mourn his death, he could finally die with content and rest in peace.

Comment: This is probably it, although it is a bit strange because when he was dying he said something like *"I don't want to die now..."* (he wanted to stay with Ai). Either he wished this too late or God is fed up with his requests.

Comment: Hampnie's wish included dying with a pang of regret. His wish wouldn't have come true if he hadn't thought, "I don't want to die now..."